# Custom SUMIF function in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Basically, I am trying to re-create Excels SUMIF function within the custom code section of SSRS. I have data that started coming in later than the majority of my data, and I want to perform a sum only if the data is available.

Please see the image attached:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsGsu.jpg)

I have tried many versions of a public function and I am still getting the #Error result.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Showing some of the things that you have tried will help others to provide you with some suggestions.

Comment: Here is a simple one I tried, no dice.

=SUM(IIF(ISNOTHING(denominator),0,numerator))

Comment: Can you post the query to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my issue was that I was missing CINT() for the field values. I added them and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can you post your answer completely for future reference? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your Numerator sum field, try this.

**Updated**

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Denominator.Value = "", 0, Fields!Numerator.Value))
```

Comment: I'm confused on the data. Is that really returning the word `NULL` in the `Denominator` field?

Comment: No, it isn't "NULL" text. It is SSMS null.

Comment: Usually in SSRS it won't show the word `NULL`. Try the update above.

Comment: Yea, still nothing. SSRS usually uses NOTHING as null. Or you can use the function ISNOTHING(), as i tried above.